# JAMA vector multiplication to get a single value

Tags: jama

I want to multiply a column matrix and row matrix in JAMA and get a single value. But JAMA returns a matrix. here is the code

```
double[] C= new double[]{1,2};
double[] D= new double[]{1,2};
double[][] x=matC.times(matD.transpose()).getArray();
    for (int i=0; i<2;i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2;j++){
            System.out.print(x[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("test 3");
```

the out put is

```
1.0 2.0 2.0 4.0 test 3
```

How can just get the value as 5?

Comment: (What are `matC` and `matD`?) It might be multiplying a row by a column. Try using `Arrays.deepString()`: `System.out.println(Arrays.deepString(X.times(Y)).getArray()) + " test 3")

Comment: I changed the code as `matC.transpose().times(matD)` and I was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Great. (It was Arrays.deepToString(), anyway…)